# Removing nested loops within python

Tags: python, numpy, nested-loops

I am trying to speed up my code. The biggest problem is a few nested loops I have (they have to iterate over 25000 cells). However, when I try to get rid of these nested loops, I get a different result and I don't seem to get why.

This is one of the nested loop:

```
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        # value added in sector i (month k+1)
        VA[i,k+1]= VA[i,k+1] - IO[j,i]*(Produc[i,k+1]/Produc[i,0])
```

This is what I did to get rid of the inner loop:

```
for in range(N):
    VA[i,k+1]=VA[i,k+1] - np.sum(IO[:,i])*(Produc[i,k+1]/Produc[i,0])
```

Thank you for very much your help.

Comment: use xrange instead of range (for Python version < 3), else it creates an array of size N every time

Comment: what is the size of IO ? you sum up from 0 to N-1 on j in the first case (inner loop) and from 0 to len(IO)-1 on j in the second case

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: trying to make your single codebase futureproof by making it very inefficient on the interpreter you're already using seems like a Bad Idea.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan, not exactly what I would call "more portable". The meaning of the code and the performance is very different. It just has the same end result in a lot of cases. 2to3 will do this transformation better.

Comment: Can you give an example of two differing results? Is it possible that the difference is due to truncation of floating point values?

Comment: @Thomas, thank you for your suggestion of using xrange (I notice a slight speed increase). The size of IO is 500*500

Comment: @bogatron, thank you for your suggestion. Maybe it is indeed a precision problem. The sum of the VA in the nested loop would be 49.6894189183, while the first suggestion of Veedrac would result in 49.7519189183. More specific, each row in VA will give a slightly different result.

Comment: Can you compute the max absolute difference between VA using the two methods?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that assigning to VA constricts the type to VA.dtype, so you can lose accuracy if VA.dtype is less precise than the result from `VA[i,k+1] - IO[j,i]*(Produc[i,k+1]/Produc[i,0])`.

To keep this rounding you'd want:

```
for i in range(N):
    # value added in sector i (month k+1)
    VA[i,k+1] -= (IO[:,i]*(Produc[i,k+1]/Produc[i,0])).astype(VA.dtype).sum()
```

...assuming you're not more happy with the more accurate version!

Some more painstaking research has shown that if the subtractions take the data through 0, the behaviour isn't perfectly emulated. I wouldn't bother though, because emulating subtle bugs is a waste of time ;).

---

Note that if you're happy with

```
for in range(N):
    VA[i,k+1]=VA[i,k+1] - np.sum(IO[:,i])*(Produc[i,k+1]/Produc[i,0])
```

you can also do

```
VA[:,k+1] -= IO.sum(axis=0) * Produc[:,k+1] / Produc[:,0]
```

which I think is equivalent.

---

Note that this assumes that `N` is the perfect fit for a lot of these. It could be that `VA[:N, :N]` is a subset of VA, in which case that's the problem and you should crop everything to `N` within the calculations.

Comment: Am I allowed to ask what the disagreement is? I have a sample data set where my answer works, so it's at least a reasonable guess.

Comment: VA[:,k+1] -= IO.sum(axis=0) * Produc[:,k+1] / Produc[:,0] looks right to me.

Comment: Your first statement is incorrect: you don't change the type by assigning **to one item** of an array. And you especially don't when you use `-=` or `+=`.

Comment: Ah, no, it's the type of the object you're adding, not of the array you're adding to. So `[32] + 1.4` would become `[33]`, and that's a rounding error that the original change didn't consider. It's an easy misunderstanding, I'll clear up the language.

Comment: Even if the dtypes of all the arrays are identical, the results will likely be different due to truncation since you are now adding/subtracting values of different magnitudes.

Comment: "Even if the dtypes of all the arrays are identical" → well, it's actually that if the dtype of all of them is, say, int64, the division will return a float anyway. // I also imagined the difference was big enough to not result in an obvious "oh, floating point truncation" but it's a point well made. I''ve no other ideas so I'm waiting for Elcok's response.

Comment: @Veedrac, thank you for your suggestions. The sum of the VA in the nested loop would be 49.6894189183, while your first suggestion would result in 49.7519189183.

Comment: What are the `dtype`s of your matrices?

Comment: Hmm I checked and it seemed that all the matrices used in this calculation are still float32 (I define all variables as float32 at the beginnning of the script, to avoid possible memory issues).

Comment: If you can provide a sample that shows this behaviour, such that I'm not just guessing, I'll take another look. Otherwise the feedback loop's going to be too small to get anywhere.